# webpack minify with global variables and methods for selective files in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have created a React JS application. I use webpack to minimize my javascript code. I need to provide one single javascript file as output(vendor + app code) to another tool which integrates this. the problem when i try to minimize my code using uglify plugin or '-p' option with webpack command webpack removes all global variables and methods as unused(esp in one particular vendor file) but they are used in my code. so is there is any to minimize using webpack but not remove global variables in some selective files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some searches and found an answer to my question.

1) To include the unused global variables and methods and not remove them while uglifying use the uglify plugin option

```
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress:{
            unused : false
        }
    })
```

the above solves the 'unused' problem

however I had one more problem that is in one of the vendor libraries there were many global functions. webpack wraps these inside a self calling function and executes.because of this the scope was affected. the global functions were local to that scope and was not available outside.so I can't pack vendor and app together as single file. may if there is any way to expose the globals that would be better.

Comment: woot this helped me!   my case is I that I had a global js function only used **inline in HTML**   ...and thus webpack didnt detect it and stripped it out contrary to what i wanted